# Docker compose removes another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a project with one basic `docker-compose.yml` file and then 2 another file - each for one environment `docker-compose.dev.yml` and `docker-compose.prod.yml`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"

services:
    app:
        build: 
            context: .
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - selenium
        networks:
            - richy

    redis:
        image: redis:3.2
        container_name: redis
        networks:
            - richy

    selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome
        container_name: selenium
        networks:
            - richy

networks:
    richy:
        driver: bridge
```

**docker-compose.dev.yml**

```
version: "2"

services:
    app:
        build: 
            args:
                env: dev
        image: richy_image:dev-latest
        container_name: richy-dev
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/richy
        ports:
            - 9000:80
        environment: 
            - ENV=dev
```

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```
version: "2"

services:
    app:
        build: 
            args:
                env: prod
        image: richy_image:prod-latest
        container_name: richy-prod
        volumes:
            - /home/grafa/workspace/prichy/richy/db.sqlite3:/var/www/richy/richy/db.sqlite3
        ports:
            - 9001:80
        environment: 
            - ENV=prod
```

I run my dev/prod environments like `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.(dev|prod).yml up`

The thing is I cannot run there both containers side by side despite I was able to do it like a month ago and few changes ago. Everytime I have running for example dev environment and I spawn docker-compose for prod environment docker spits out this:

```
redis is up-to-date
selenium is up-to-date
Recreating richy-dev
```

which is strange because why it wants to recreate the richy-dev container when I'm starting the richy-prod.

Maybe there is a conflict in my config files. Can you guys please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like it may be because both services are named `app`

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and report results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically to differentiate between container names of two environments, you will need to define project name explicitly. otherwise it takes the name based on the folder name.

> you can use -p or the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable for that.

taken from: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2982#issuecomment-186835033

Comment: Thank you. I've wrote an article with whole solution https://medium.com/@n1_/docker-and-your-development-a-production-environments-857067a9bfc0